# Class 'cassandra_ColumnPath' not found in

Tags: php, cassandra

i follow step by step installation which can be find https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP on Centos 5.6 machine 
and i got this error in apache log

[Fri Aug 26 14:20:20 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.67] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'cassandra_ColumnPath' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 29

anyone have any ideas?

PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2009 11:44:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

apache-cassandra-0.8.4

thrift-0.7.0

Comment: Uhm, if you need to install trift - why do you install cassandra?

Comment: actually i install cassandra and want to connect it using php throught trift, i follow steps https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP
but after i run on the php examples given , i just got the class not found error in the apche log

Comment: did you fix it ? if yes, how did you fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the bottom of that post suggests, you really need to use a high-level client that builds on top of what Thrift generates.  Otherwise, it's a slow and painful process.

I recommend looking at:

- [phpcassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa) (Disclosure: I maintain this library)
- [SimpleCassie](http://code.google.com/p/simpletools-php/wiki/SimpleCassie) (I can't vouch for how well it works, but it seems fine.)

Both of these libraries bundle the Thrift generated code, so you don't even have to worry about setting that part up.